# Can't start the app with Carthage dependency (SnapKit)

Tags: swift, carthage, snapkit

Suppose I have a framework that depends on SnapKit, we use Carthage to build all the dependencies

In my framework's Cartfile I have

```
github "SnapKit/SnapKit" ~> 5.0.0
```

Everyting is building correctly, then I add framework to the project and also I add `copy-frameworks` build phase, but on app's launch I get

```
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SnapKit.framework/SnapKit
  Referenced from: path/to/Myframework.framework/MyFramework
  Reason: Incompatible library version: MyFramework requires version 1.0.0 or later, but SnapKit provides version 0.0.0
```

Is it somehow possible to build SnapKit with Carthage with the correct version or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround I deleted Compatibility Version and Current Library Version from Build Settings here

[image]